# Почему HTTP/2 является бинарным?

Tags: http, binary

Почему HTTP/2 является бинарным, а HTTP 1.1 текстовым? По моему и то и то бинарное, т.к. компьютер не имеет искусственного интеллекта и не понимает текст как таковой.

Не пойму принципиальной разницы. Если данные чисто текстовые в HTTP1.1 и HTTP/2 разницы никакой не будет? Или будет условно из-за сжатия заголовка?
Но по HTTP1.1 же и так передавались бинарники, помимо текста (фото, видео и т.д.), например при загрузке в поле формы, то получается HTTp1.1 тоже по сути бинарный?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/2 использует отличное от HTTP 1.1 кодирование. HTTP 1.1 использует символы US-ASCII для кодирования, HTTP/2 не имеет этого ограничения и может использовать любые произвольные байты. Утверждение, что обе версии протокола используют бинарное кодирование с одной стороны верно, ведь любой текст представляется компьютером в бинарном виде, но с другой стороны не верно, так как несжатые сообщения в HTTP 1.1 могут быть выведены на экран в виде текста без предварительного декодирования и прочитаны человеком. Сообщения в HTTP/2, выведенные на экран с использованием кодировки US-ASCII будут выглядеть как случайный набор символов, не имеющий для человека особого смысла и не может быть разобрана даже хорошо подготовленным человеком, так как не все байты, используемые для передачи этого сообщения имеют графическое представление в этой кодировке.

Comment: Почему HTTP 1.1 использует US-ASCII? А как же UTF-8? Или любая другая кодировка? А передача файлов, фото видео и т.д.?

Comment: Для кодирования заголовков всё равно используется US-ASCII, потому что этого требует спецификация протокола, тело сообщения может иметь свою кодировку.

Comment: Что-то я так и не понял, что является в протоколе бинарным, только заголовки?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев служебные структуры протокола (заголовки, по большей части) в US-ASCII, а данные он может передавать какие угодно. В HTTP/2 же служебные структуры тоже бинарные.

Comment: Если не в ASCII, то очевидно в бинарном виде, т.е. там могут быть произвольные байты со значениями от 0 до 255. Я думаю, мне нужно дополнить свой ответ объяснением, что такое бинарное кодирование и описанием его плюсов.

Comment: Что-то я совсем запутался. Например, нужно передать слово "hello". В чем будет разница по HTTP1.1 и HTTP2. Если HTTP1 закодирует всю эту байду в UTF-8 это будет, насколько я понимаю, 01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111. Тогда что будет в HTTP2?

Comment: Разница между бинарным и текстовым протоколом наглядно показана на этом слайде: https://cdn.wp.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Slide-3-HTTP2-Inside-Binary-1.png

Comment: Бинарные данные можно представить в двоичном, шестнадцатеричном или любом другом виде. Второе сообщение со слайда в таком представлении выглядело бы так: https://i.imgur.com/GIohdsc.png